# A function with a console log output inside console.log prints undefined

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

```
function haha(){
  console.log('haha');
}

console.log(haha());
```

Prints:

```
haha
undefined
```

Is it because if you don't specify return in a function it will return undefined and this is what the second console.log is outputting?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Yes is the answer.

Comment: Is it because if you don't specify return in a function it will return undefined ==> for this answer is yes.  is this what the second console.log is outputting? ==> for this answer is no. The second function outputting 'haha' but it returns undefined. But this undefined is not returned as part of first function.

Answer (score 4):

It returns `undefined` because basically your function doesn't return anything.

You could e.g. return a *"haha"* string or whatever you like.

```js
function haha(){
  console.log('haha');
  return 'haha';
}

console.log(haha());
```

Comment: Id recommend changing this to two functions, one logging inside and calling, the other returning and logging outside.

Comment: @NickA The reason being?

Comment: @MarinaDunst If you `console.log` the whole, called function, you will log exactly what function has returned. Since in your particular case the function doesn't return anything, you are receiving `undefined` output (there's nothing to log).

Comment: @Kind user Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because if you don't specify return in a function it will return
>   undefined and this is what the second console.log is outputting?

Yes, `console.log()` prints the arguments passed to it. Arguments passed to it in the second time is the returned value of `haha()` which is `undefined`

First console log is the due to the console.log inside `haha`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how undefined ends up inside the second console.log